# How to compare datetime and time in phpmysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

Just one question: Is it possible to compare the datetime format and time format?

I have table `employee_attendance` (datetime type) and table `employee_schedule` (time type) and this is to determine IF the employee was late.

please check out my code.

```
$CheckInNew  = strtotime('2013-06-05 08:47:53');
$OnDutyTimeNew   = strtotime('08:00:00');

if($CheckIn > $OnDutyTimeNew){

// confirming that the employee is late

} else {

// confirming that the employee is NOT late

}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: Depends on what you intend to do with it. Do you have a date on which the OnDutyTimeNew occurs? To compare you have to assume the data on which this is happening. If no date is given, do you want to check the same date as CheckInNew?

Comment: You can try my answer.=)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$CheckInNew  = date('B',strtotime('2013-06-05 08:47:53'));
$OnDutyTimeNew   = date('B',strtotime('08:00:00'));

if ($CheckInNew > $OnDutyTimeNew)
    echo 'late!';
else
    echo 'early!';
```

I use be as keyword for `Internet Swatch` Time.. For more info, [here's the link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

**UPDATE:**
[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nwf-7zj)

Comment: Never heard of the "Internet Swatch" time. You never stop learning.

Answer (score 0):

Why not parse the time in to a timestamp, then just compare using function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)()

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL:

```
-- checkin is the column with their checkin time
-- scheduled is the column with their scheduled time
SELECT
    TIMEDIFF(TIME(checkin), scheduled) AS diff
```

If `diff` is negative, then they're on time. If it is a positive number they are late

**Reference**

- [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)
- [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to compare to the same date as the CheckInDateOnly date.

You could do this by converting the datetime to a date only, and adding that to the OnDutyTime variable.

```
$checkInDateTime = strtotime('2013-06-05 08:47:53');
$checkInDateOnly = date("Y-m-d", $checkInDateTime);
$OnDutyTimeNewWithSameDateAsCheckIn = strtotime($checkInDateOnly . '08:00:00');

echo ($checkInDateTime > $OnDutyTimeNewWithSameDateAsCheckIn ? "Late" : "Early");
```

Usage example: [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3i0-ia4)

Comment: You're welcome. My answer is comparable to @Christian Mark, except for the date format but it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Since the date format contains leading zero, you can simply use pure string compare to compare the date.

```
$checkInDateTime  = '2013-06-05 08:47:53';
$dutyTime = '08:00:00';

if (substr($checkInDateTime, -8) > $dutyTime) {
    echo "Late";
} else {
    echo "Early";
}
```

Normally, a single day divides into 1,440 minutes. `Swatch Internet time` divides a single day into 1000 beat. Therefore 1 beat = 1.44 minutes. Using `Swatch Internet time` to compare a normal time is not accurate because it does not include seconds and there is minute error (at least this is what I believe).